# How to attach source libraries (jar) for RichFaces to a web project?

Tags: web, netbeans, jar, richfaces, jsf-2.2

The two folders:

I'm confused about jar attachment. I can place them into the /src/config/lib or into the /web/WEB-INF/lib folder as well. When should I copy my files where? What is the difference between the two solutions?

Namespaces:

In my web project I put the jars into the /src/config/lib folder and add this into the "Source package folder" but the namespaces (for RichFaces) do not appear as suggestions at namespace definition (xmlns:a4j= + ctrl-space) in NetBeans. How can I make them visible in the list?

I put this files into the /src/config/lib folder:

```
richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar
cssparser-0.9.18.jar
guava-19.0.jar
sac-1.3.jar
```

Its documentation says that it is enough for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

For the web project the libs should end up in WEB-INF/lib. If you are not using maven to setup the project I strongly suggest you start using something like maven. Makes your library management a lot easier.

It's been a long time but for what I remember the <a4j: + ctrl-space starts working after you include the namespace in the xhtml file.
Like:

```
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
     ...
  </html>
```

One other thing is that I would not start new projects using Richfaces (don't know if your project is a new one). For new projects I tend to create rest services for the real fancy GUI stuff and use things like Angular. Modern JSF already has a lot of ajax support so the need for that part of richfaces is very little. On the graphical side RF is a bit old fashioned. Modern UI sites have a different look with much more space between elements.

Comment: Thx for the answer. 1., I want to insert the namespaces with the suggestions with Ctrl+Space. 2., I prefer PrimeFaces just I want to try something out. 3., NetBeans manage the project but I dont understand what is the difference to place the jars here or there.